# Intuitive Explanation for the Wait time of 2 Queuing Models with 1 server vs 2 with equal rate

Tags: markov-process, queueing-theory

So I'm having a hard time understanding intuitively why the bottom queuing model behaves the way it does

The arrival rate of both systems is exponentially distributed with a rate of 3 customers per minute

$\text{Model 1:}$
$$M/M/1 \text{ , serving time} \sim Ex(4)$$
4 as in 4 customers per minute.

$\text{Model 2:}$
$$M/M/2 \text{ , serving times for both are }\sim Ex(2)$$

In other words, the 2 servers in Model 2 are as efficient as the 1 server in Model 1.

So the wait time for the arriving customer is $1$ minute in Model 1 vs $1.22$ minutes in Model 2.

The wait time in the queue is $.75$ minutes in Model 1 vs $.72$ minutes for Model 2.

I can do the math behind it, but I have no idea why logically it works this way

Comment: So $\overline{N}^1 = \overline{N}^1_q + \overline{N}^1_s$ and $\overline{N}^2 = \overline{N}^2_q+ \overline{N}^2_s$, where $\overline{N}^i$ denotes total average number of jobs in system $i \in \{1,2\}$, and $\overline{N}^i_q, \overline{N}^i_s$ decomposes into jobs in queue and server/s, respectively. We know $\overline{N}^1 \leq \overline{N}^2$ since system 1 always serves at the full processing rate 4/min, while system 2 only serves at this rate when there are 2 or more.     Little's theorem gives $\overline{N}^1_s = \lambda/4$, $\overline{N}^2_s = (\lambda_1/2) + (\lambda_2/2)=\lambda/2$.

Comment: So, $\overline{N}_s^2 = 2\overline{N}_s^1$.  Since there are on average twice as many jobs in the servers of system 2 as there are jobs in the server of system 1,  it is possible to have more jobs queued in system 1, even though the total average number of jobs in system 1 is less than that of system 2. Intuitively, since system 2 has 2 servers, you can think of one of the servers as taking a job that would ordinarily be queued (in a 1-server system), removing it from the queue, and serving it.